# CSS table layout - table-cell height not reducing when reducing window size

Tags: html, css, tablecell

I have got one problem with layout based on a CSS table, i.e. with `display:table`, `display:table-row`, `display:table-cell` and so on.

You can verify the problem is this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e14v9dnw/2/).

The div called map is really a `table-cell` and I don't know why when I reduce the height of the window it doesn't get reflected in the `table-cell`, but only when I reduce `height` (when reducing width everything works fine).

Please, take a look at the console of chrome or firebug to see the results of console.log("New extent: ", extent). The complete code of the fiddle is the following:

```js
var map;
    
require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map) {
  map = new Map("map", {
    basemap: "topo",
    center: [-122.45, 37.75], // longitude, latitude
    zoom: 13
  });

  map.on("resize", function(extent){
    console.log("New extent: ", extent);
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #FFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
}
div#container {
  display:table;
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  border-spacing:0px;       /* Con border-spacing ya no hay que poner margin en los table-row y table-cell */
  border:0; padding:0;
}
div#row1 {
  display:table-row;
  width:100%; height:72px;
  border:0; padding:0;       /* Con border-spacing ya no hay que poner margin en los table-row y table-cell */
}
div#row2 {
  display:table-row;
  width:100%;                /* No hace falta poner height, se rellena ya todo, no se mezclan px y % */
  border:0; padding:0;       /* Con border-spacing ya no hay que poner margin en los table-row y table-cell */
}


div#header {
  z-index:1;
  display:table-cell;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%; height:72px;
  border:0; padding:0;       /* Con border-spacing ya no hay que poner margin en los table-row y table-cell */
  background-color:#3567AE;
}


div#map {
  z-index:1;
  display:table-cell;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  border:0; padding:0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/js/esri/css/esri.css">
<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="row1">
    <div id="header"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="row2">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work when you increase the height, just not when you make the height smaller.

> By CSS 2.1 rules, the height of a table cell is “the minimum height required by the content”.

Since you are dynamically filling the div content by loading the map, the full height is occupied and if you try to make it smaller, it will not allow you to because the content is still there.
So why not change your layout so you no longer need `display: table-cell;`?

```
div#map {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%; 
  height: calc(100% - 72px);
  border:0; padding:0;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e14v9dnw/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your comments, Dark. I wasn't really aware of this "problem" with table-cell. Now, it's time to make it work and follow the information you provided. This is the final code that works (much simpler and less html):

```js
var map;
 
require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map) {
 map = new Map("map", {
  basemap: "topo",
  center: [-122.45, 37.75], // longitude, latitude
  zoom: 13
 });

 map.on("resize", function(extent){
  console.log("New extent: ", extent);
 });
});
```

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin:0; border:0; padding:0;
}
body {
 background-color: #FFF;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
}
div#header {
 overflow:hidden;
 width:100%; height:72px;
 margin:0; border:0; padding:0;
 background-color:#3567AE;
}
 
div#map {
 overflow:hidden;
 width:100%; height:calc(100% - 72px);
 margin:0; border:0; padding:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/js/esri/css/esri.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"/>
<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/"></script>
                                                                                
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: That looks a lot simpler/better indeed! :)